# How can I export a variable in bash where the variable name is comprised of two variables?

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I'm trying to export variables inside of a for loop where I wanted each iteration of the loop to change what variable was being written to.  I've been looking for the right syntax to satisfy exporting like this in bash, but none of I've tried have worked.  What is the proper way to do this?

To add more detail, my hope is when the loop runs, I would be exporting FVAR0 on the first run, FVAR1 on the second, FVAR2 on the third, and so on.

Originally I had tried `export FVAR$i`

`export "${!FVAR[$i]}"` is my most recent guess.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
for i in 0 1 2 3 4
do
    export "${!FVAR[$i]}"=$(ls ./run/$i)
done


10:36:10 Thu Jan 24 ::  ./uploader.sh
+ for i in 0 1 2 3 4
++ ls ./run/0
+ export =
./uploader.sh: line 5: export: `=': not a valid identifier
+ for i in 0 1 2 3 4
++ ls ./run/1
+ export =
./uploader.sh: line 5: export: `=': not a valid identifier
+ for i in 0 1 2 3 4
++ ls ./run/2
+ export =
./uploader.sh: line 5: export: `=': not a valid identifier
+ for i in 0 1 2 3 4
++ ls ./run/3
+ export =
./uploader.sh: line 5: export: `=': not a valid identifier
+ for i in 0 1 2 3 4
++ ls ./run/4
+ export =
./uploader.sh: line 5: export: `=': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Do you not have an array called `FVAR`? This is what you're using.

Comment: I've edited my question.  I'm hoping to get the loop to change which FVAR is being written to.  There should be no "FVAR" but there should be FVAR0 FVAR1 FVAR2 etc

Comment: It looks like you actually do want to use an array here.  Is there a reason that you want to create environment variables rather than ordinary shell variables? What are you planning to use the `ls` output for (there are much better ways to get file listings, that preserve whitespaces etc. in filenames).

Comment: Well this is where it gets dicey.  Explained here, exporting arrays won't happen:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script

Comment: Don't pay any mind to what's going into the variable, all I need is the syntax to allow it to export.  lt was just a simple place holder so I could cleanly post the question.

Comment: I'm not going "pay no mind" to what this script is supposed to achieve. If you are wanting to save pathnames to various variables, then this is _not_ the way to do it.

Comment: You're not wrong, but that's not what I was trying to focus on.  I wanted to isolate one part of the problem first.  As shown in the answer below, I see now it's legal to do "export FVAR$x" in a for loop.  Now I'm turning my attention to the aspect you're considering.

Comment: This is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I disagree.  I wanted one specific piece of information - for purely academic purposes, and I got it.  Not every question will be about 'a solution' sometimes it's just about understanding a finer point on something, in this case, syntax.

Comment: @Kusalananda, meh, exporting variables called `xyz1`, `xyz2` etc. is as good a workaround for not being able to actually export arrays as anything else is. At least as the shell doesn't allow for exporting a variable called `xyz[1]`.

Comment: @ilkkachu You're assuming they need to be exported.

Comment: @Kusalananda, well, they obviously want to export multiple pieces of data, I  assume to pass to some child process. Sure, there are workarounds, you could stick the data in a temporary file or pipe it in or whatever, but not having a sensible way to use the environment for that (even between scripts using the same interpreter) is rather annoying if you happen to need it.

Comment: @ilkkachu Passing data to a child process using the command line is a fairly standard way of passing data, especially pathnames that needs to be processed somehow.  No need to export variables for that.  Environment variables are most often used to alter behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for x in 0 1 2 3; do
    export FVAR$x="Is's $x"
done

env | grep FVAR
```

Executing:

```
$ ./fvar.sh 
FVAR3=Is's 3
FVAR2=Is's 2
FVAR1=Is's 1
FVAR0=Is's 0
```

Comment: That's bizarre, a coworker of mine and I have both tried that, as I stated above, that's the very first thing we tried.  Is $i reserved?  The only differences I see between yours and mine is you used 'x' instead, and you put a semi-colon in your for loop, neither of which seem to matter since I back-ported your change to my loop, now it's fine.  Thank you for the sanity-reinforcement.

Answer (score 0):

```
export "${!FVAR[$i]}"=...
```

This would assume `FVAR` is an array, and try to use its element in index `$i` as a name of a variable to expand on that command line. (That is, `a=11; b=22; c=33; p=(a b c); echo ${!p[1]}` would print `22` since `p[1]` is `b`, `$b` is `22`.)

`FVAR[0]` etc. don't hold names of variables in that script, so that expansion results in an empty string.

You should be able to use just

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    export "FVAR$i=$(generate some value from $i)"
done
```

as `export` processes the variable name after expansions. This is not the case with a regular assignment, however. `FVAR$i=$(...)` doesn't work.

---

Of course, depending on what you're doing, there might be other ways, like sticking all the values together in one variable, and exporting that.

```
FVARS="$(generate some value from 1)"
for i in 2 3 4 5 ; do
    FVARS+=":$(generate some value from $i)"
done
export FVARS
```

Though that requires reserving some character to use as a separator, and 
arranging to put the separator in the right place etc...

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!